# What happens if you turn on multiple VPN connections?

Tags: networking, network-manager, 17.10, vpn, openvpn

I'm on ubuntu 17 and i just added a few vpn options. I noticed you can turn all of them on, but which one takes precedent? If all of them are on, do they just fall back on the other if one of them fails?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

That highly depends on how they are configured.  Some tunnels are configured to route only traffic that is destined for the other end of the tunnel, while others are configured to route all traffic.  Which one takes precedent (where your traffic goes) is highly dependent on any routes they might setup and the order in which you enable them.  If you'd like an answer specific to your configuration, you'll need to provide those configurations and your routing table (both while they're connected and disconnected).

Guessing from the names I'm going to assume both of those tunnels are configured to pass *all* traffic.  If that's the case, it's likely that the second tunnel you enabled established it's tunnel *through* the first tunnel you enabled.  This probably doesn't make you any more secure and will likely slow down your connection.

Comment: I would - quite roughly - distinguish between "corporate VPNs" and "privacy VPNs". "Corporate VPNs" are the ones people use to access resources on some internal network (usually a corporate network) from outside, eg. for remote working. "Privacy VPNs" are the ones people use to hide/change their IP address, so that it looks that they access Internet from somewhere else than they actually are. The former usually pass only _some_ traffic (although they may be as well configured to pass all traffic), the latter usually pass _all_ traffic.

Comment: That distinction is not useful within the scope of the question.  Also, since it is already established that tunnels can be configured to handle only certain routes vs all routes; that distinction is already established within the context of the question as the question was concerning "what happens..." vs "whats the difference..."